# Rendering to texture and attribute location

Tags: javascript, webgl, vertex-attributes

I am using webgl and what I want to do is first render to a texture, then use that texture to render on screen, and I encounter a problem with an attribute in the first step render.

I will try to explain in a few words what I am trying to do. First I want to use a fragment shader to render to a texture something that uses an attribute, then use that texture to render to screen, and repeat the steps for the next frame. But when I try to render with the framebuffer bound that attribute (pos) has invalid values, I mean, no value at all.

I wrote a little demo that shows my problem:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas); 

var program_init, program_pers, tex, fb;

function init() {
 var verts = [
    1,  1,
   -1,  1,
   -1, -1,
    1,  1,
   -1, -1,
    1, -1,
 ];
    
    var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    tex = gl.createTexture();
    fb = gl.createFramebuffer();

    program_init = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vshader-init", "fshader-init"], ["pos"]);
    program_pers = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vshader-pers", "fshader-pers"], ["a_position"]);
}

function renderToTexture(gl, time) {
 gl.useProgram(program_init);
 
 var timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program_init, 'time');
 gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, time);

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
 gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);

 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
};

function renderToScreen(gl) {
 gl.useProgram(program_pers);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}; 

init();
requestAnimationFrame(function(){
 renderToTexture(gl, arguments[0]);
 renderToScreen(gl);
 
 requestAnimationFrame( arguments.callee );
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
body { background-color: darkslategrey }
```

```html
<script src="http://greggman.github.com/webgl-fundamentals/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="vshader-init" type="vs/shader">
attribute vec4 pos;
varying vec2 uv;

void main() {
 gl_Position = pos;
 uv = pos.xy * .5 + .5;
}    
</script>
<script id="fshader-init" type="fs/shader">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 uv;

uniform float time;

void main() {
 float t = floor(time / 1000.);
 vec3 color;
 color.x = sin(t*uv.x);
 color.y = tan(t*uv.y);
 color.z = cos(t);
 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
</script>

<script id="vshader-pers" type="vs/shader">
attribute vec4 a_position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
 gl_Position = a_position;
 v_texcoord = a_position.xy * .5 + .5;
}    
</script>
<script id="fshader-pers" type="fs/sahder">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
void main() {
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, v_texcoord);
}
</script>

<body>
 <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

If I comment the line 38,39 from the javascript code (the binding of the frameBuffer) and line 54 (the rendering to screen code, that runs a different program) we can see that it renders corectly and the name "pos" is given the right values.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas); 

var program_init, program_pers, tex, fb;

function init() {
 var verts = [
    1,  1,
   -1,  1,
   -1, -1,
    1,  1,
   -1, -1,
    1, -1,
 ];
    
    var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    tex = gl.createTexture();
    fb = gl.createFramebuffer();

    program_init = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vshader-init", "fshader-init"], ["pos"]);
    program_pers = createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vshader-pers", "fshader-pers"], ["a_position"]);
}

function renderToTexture(gl, time) {
 gl.useProgram(program_init);
 
 var timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program_init, 'time');
 gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, time);

 gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

 //gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
 //gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);

 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
};

function renderToScreen(gl) {
 gl.useProgram(program_pers);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}; 

init();
requestAnimationFrame(function(){
 renderToTexture(gl, arguments[0]);
 //renderToScreen(gl);
 
 requestAnimationFrame( arguments.callee );
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
body { background-color: darkslategrey }
```

```html
<script src="http://greggman.github.com/webgl-fundamentals/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="vshader-init" type="vs/shader">
attribute vec4 pos;
varying vec2 uv;

void main() {
 gl_Position = pos;
 uv = pos.xy * .5 + .5;
}    
</script>
<script id="fshader-init" type="fs/shader">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 uv;

uniform float time;

void main() {
 float t = floor(time / 1000.);
 vec3 color;
 color.x = sin(t*uv.x);
 color.y = tan(t*uv.y);
 color.z = cos(t);
 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
</script>

<script id="vshader-pers" type="vs/shader">
attribute vec4 a_position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
 gl_Position = a_position;
 v_texcoord = a_position.xy * .5 + .5;
}    
</script>
<script id="fshader-pers" type="fs/shader">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
void main() {
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, v_texcoord);
}
</script>

<body>
 <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

I do not know much about how it is supposed to work and I am a bit into the dark. I am sure I'm missing something important, but I can't find anywhere what. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You're not supposed to recreate your whole state in every frame. Initialize everything first, use it to render in the loop.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz thank you, I have modified my code to initialize all in one place. But still can't figure out why I can't use 'pos' in vshader-init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your framebuffer texture is 1x1 pixels big. What do you expect to see? You're rendering a single pixel.

Also note that unless your framebuffer is the same size as the canvas you'll want to call `gl.viewport` and set it to the size of the thing you rendering after each call to `gl.bindFramebuffer`

You probably also want to not create the texture every frame. Here's your code with those things changed.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl"); 

var program_init, program_pers, tex, fb;
var fbWidth = 400;
var fbHeight = 300;

function init() {
 var verts = [
    1,  1,
   -1,  1,
   -1, -1,
    1,  1,
   -1, -1,
    1, -1,
 ];
    
    var vertBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
 gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuffer);
 gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(verts), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
 gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
    
    tex = gl.createTexture();
    fb = gl.createFramebuffer();

    program_init = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vshader-init", "fshader-init"], ["pos"]);
    program_pers = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vshader-pers", "fshader-pers"], ["a_position"]);
  
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, fbWidth, fbHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
    // make non power-of-2 texture renderable
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);

 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
 gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
}

function renderToTexture(gl, time) {
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, fbWidth, fbHeight);
  
    gl.useProgram(program_init);
 
 var timeLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program_init, 'time');
 gl.uniform1f(timeLocation, time);

 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
};

function renderToScreen(gl) {    
 gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);
 gl.useProgram(program_pers);
 gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}; 

init();
requestAnimationFrame(function(){
 renderToTexture(gl, arguments[0]);
 renderToScreen(gl);
 
 requestAnimationFrame( arguments.callee );
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
body { background-color: darkslategrey }
```

```html
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>

<script id="vshader-init" type="vs/shader">
attribute vec4 pos;
varying vec2 uv;

void main() {
 gl_Position = pos;
 uv = pos.xy * .5 + .5;
}    
</script>
<script id="fshader-init" type="fs/shader">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 uv;

uniform float time;

void main() {
 float t = floor(time / 1000.);
 vec3 color;
 color.x = sin(t*uv.x);
 color.y = tan(t*uv.y);
 color.z = cos(t);
 
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
}
</script>

<script id="vshader-pers" type="vs/shader">
attribute vec4 a_position;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
 gl_Position = a_position;
 v_texcoord = a_position.xy * .5 + .5;
}    
</script>
<script id="fshader-pers" type="fs/sahder">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler2D u_sampler;
void main() {
 gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_sampler, v_texcoord);
}
</script>

<body>
 <canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```